# Jquery syntax meaning - difference between $(x) and x

Tags: jquery

I know that when we have an element with id='someId', we can access it with Jquery like this:

```
$('#someId')
```

But sometimes when we have a variable:

```
var x;
```

We use just `x` or `$(x)`.

When do we use `$(x)` instead of `x`? When do we use `$($(x))` instead of `x`?

Comment: You never use `$($(x))`, first off. Next off, that's `$('#someId')`. Also, `$` is just a function that does different things depending on what it's passed. Check the docs.

Comment: Please read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/. *When do we use `$(x)` instead of `x`?* ... depends on what `x` refers to!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(x)` creates a jQuery object containing `x` (which should be a DOM node) or the elements contained in `x` (if it's an array or jQuery object).

You use `x` if you just want the plain DOM object (assuming `x` is one), e.g. `x.id` to get the element's ID as there is no need to create a jQuery object for that - it would be even more to write: `$(x).prop('id')`.

You **never** use `$($(x))`! There is just **no reason to do that ever**. While it works it is just like `$(x)` except the fact that you first create a jQuery object and then put the contents of that jQuery object into a new jQuery object.

---

If you need the other way (jQuery object => DOM object) there are quite a few ways. `y[0]` is the easiest way to get the first element; use `y.get()` if you want an array with all elements contained in the jQuery object `y`.

Comment: You can access ID simply with x.id if x is DOM element, no need to wrap with jQuery

Comment: Correct. But not really related.

Comment: @ThiefMaster About $($(x)) - I believe we use it when we have body inside another body. Is it not true?

Comment: That statement doesn't make much sense. But no, you **never** want to use it!